# jQuery Templating - Associating data to template DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-templates

I am using jQuery's template plugin rendering several row items similiar to this:

```
var clientData = [
    { name: "Rey Bango", id: 1 },     
    { name: "Mark Goldberg", id: 2 },     
    { name: "Jen Statford", id: 3 } ]; 

<script id="clientTemplate" type="text/html">     
    <li><${name}</li> 
</script> 

$("#clientTemplate").tmpl(clientData).appendTo( "ul" );
```

I am wondering if it is possible to make use of [jQuery's data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function to be able to associate each row item back to an identifier for updating.

Normally you could do something like this:

```
$.each(clientData, function(idx, item) {
    $('<li></li>').appendTo('ul#clientTemplate')
        .text(item.name)
        .data('clientId', item.id);
});

$('ul#clientTemplate li').click(function() {
    updateClient($(this).data('clientId'));
});
```

However you don't have this type of control when templating.

***Note***: I'd rather not use new hidden elements to store this data on each row, or additional attributes on the elements if I don't have to.

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery Templates plugin includes the [tmplItem](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmplitem/) function that allows you to get back to the actual data associated with any element rendered by a template.

So, you would be able to do something like:

```
var client = $("li").first().tmplItem().data
```

In this case `client` would be your data:

```
{ name: "Rey Bango", id: 1 }
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fvhj4/

Answer (score 1):

This could be a workaround:

```
$("#clientTemplate").tmpl(clientData).filter("li").each(function(i){
   $(this).data(clientData[i].id);
}).appendTo( "ul" );
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers